# Vertical CSS bar chart appearing upside-down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a simple vertical thermometer with CSS. I took some sample code from a tutorial which had the "mercury" in a horizontal thermometer growing from left to right.

Now that I am trying to make a vertical bar, how can I make the "mercury" grow from bottom to top?

It's coming out like this: [image: upside down bar]
But, I want the red section to be aligned at the bottom of the grey.

I've tried adding `top: 100%` to `#vertmeter-bar` which starts the red section in the right place. But, providing a negative `height` attribute for `#vertmeter-bar` doesn't seem to work.

Here's my CSS:

```
#vertmeter
{
  height:350px;
  width:30px; 
  background-color:#D1D7DF;
}   
#vertmeter_bar
{
  background-color:#CF3500;
  width:100%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="vertmeter">
<div id="vertmeter_bar" style="height:0%;">
</div>
</div>
```

And a jquery fragment to animate a transition:

```
$('#vertmeter_bar').animate({height:"10%"}, 1000, 'swing');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#vertmeter
{
  height:350px;
  width:30px; 
  background-color:#D1D7DF;
  position:relative;
}   
#vertmeter_bar
{
  background-color:#CF3500;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Some positioning with you css will solve this:

```
#vertmeter
{
  height:350px;
  width:30px; 
  background-color:#D1D7DF;
    position:relative
}   
#vertmeter_bar
{
  background-color:#CF3500;
  width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

See example - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/wpPfd/